# How to properly handle forms with different data to receive and different to POST in ASP NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have two classes:

```
public class SomeInfo
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> SomeDictionary1 { get; init; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> SomeDictionary2 { get; init; }
    public string DisplayName { get; init; }
    public string LogoUri { get; init; }
    public bool DeselectionAllowed { get; init; }
}
```

and

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public bool Denied { get; set; }
    public string[] ConsentedSomeDictionary1Keys { get; set; } = Array.Empty<string>();
    public string[] ConsentedSomeDictionary2Keys { get; set; } = Array.Empty<string>();
    public bool Remember { get; set; }
}
```

The class `SomeInfo` is class that I want to display to user and the class `ViewModel` is class that I want to receive in my backend. So what shall I do to achieve support for this scenario if I cant use two view models in one view?

Comment: The model that you use to populate a view and the model that you receive from any given request are entirely unrelated.  What have you tried and what didn't work?

Comment: Build another class that contains an instance of the first class and an instance of the second class

Comment: Did you mean, you would like to build a dynamic kind of controller which can handle different kind of data coming from form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you submitting the data you can try to change the names of the inputs,so that they will be binded to the properties of ViewModel by default.here is a demo to bind the keys of `SomeDictionary1` and `SomeDictionary2` to `ConsentedSomeDictionary1Keys` and `ConsentedSomeDictionary2Keys`:

action:

```
[HttpGet]
        public IActionResult TestModel()
        {

            return View(new SomeInfo {  SomeDictionary1=new Dictionary<string, string> { {"UK", "London"},{"USA", "Washington"},{"India", "Mumbai"}},
                                        SomeDictionary2=new Dictionary<string, string> { { "1","one"},{ "2","two"},{ "3","three"} }
            });
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult TestModel(ViewModel viewModel)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
```

view:

```
@model SomeInfo
<form method="post">
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.SomeDictionary1.Count; i++)
    {
        <input name="ConsentedSomeDictionary1Keys[@i]" value="@Model.SomeDictionary1.ElementAt(i).Key" />
       
    }
    @for (var i = 0; i < Model.SomeDictionary2.Count; i++)
    {
        <input name="ConsentedSomeDictionary2Keys[@i]" value="@Model.SomeDictionary2.ElementAt(i).Key" />
      
    }
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Nice answer, but I got idea that I can use ViewData to pass model to client and use ViewModel to POST data. Is it common or valid approach for asp net core?